# How can I remove a space, multiple space or tab from the start of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, formatting

I have strings in a file that I read. Some have space(s) or tabs at the start. Is there an easy way I can remove the space and tab (whitespace stuff)?

For example

```
var abc = "   def";
```

What I want is to remove the things before the "def".

thanks,

Update: I believe this is the correct answer:

```
char[] arr = new char[] { '\t', ' ' }; // Trim these characters
text = text.TrimStart(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the all the help but it seems none of the suggestions did what I needed :-( I found a solution and have added this. I think this works okay.

Comment: if that answer works for you, you should post it as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @Jason: I have no clue what you tested, but `TrimStart` without parameters works just fine: `var text = "\t  abc"; text = text.TrimStart();`. `text` will now contain only "abc".

Answer (score 9):

Use [`string.TrimStart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx):

```
var result = abc.TrimStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in String methods.

abc.Trim()

Comment: Actually it should be TrimStart if you only want to remove the leading space

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Trim method

```
abc.Trim()
```

Comment: This also removes whitespaces at the end of the string.